# how to hide keyboard when entry is focused in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im trying to hide a soft keyboard in android device by having the entry focused by default i.e., when the page is loaded entry should be focused automatically and keyboard should be hidden

Can anyone please  help me on this.

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.Control.RequestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.FromContext(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.ApplicationContext);
        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window.DecorView.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
    }
```

Comment: Please add to question **why** you want to do this. This likely only makes sense if the entry will NOT be filled by the user. E.g., using a bluetooth scanner. If you say that, then someone can give you appropriate advice. OR you can **google** for the many previous questions on the topic of using a bluetooth scanner with a xamarin forms entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the soft keyboard status as hidden. Refer [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)
Since you are developing in Xamarin,
Please try adding below piece of code in the OnElementChanged of the Custom Renderer
**var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;

window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);**

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
     {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
                window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);
                Control.RequestFocus();
                 if ((e.OldElement == null) && (Control != null))
                {
                    var edittext = (EditText)Control;
                    edittext.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
                }
     }
```

This will hide the Keyboard on Page Load

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace App2_XF.Droid
{
public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
           
            Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when we use this line  Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null; we are not able to see the cursor. In my case i want to see the cursor in the entry so that we can get the scanned data from scanner but the keyboard should not be shown.